# How to programmatically run Python unittest tests

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have the following tests from [the `unittest` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html).

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # Check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

How do I run the above test from another Python program and be able to inspect the results and what tests have failed, if any?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450824/getting-the-results-of-unittest-programatically/51451273#51451273

Comment: That worked well but I have 2 questions 1) re-running `test = main(module='tests', exit=False)` in the interpreter doesn't reload the code also how do I parse the result eg. `<unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=3 errors=0 failures=1>`? Thanks

Comment: Did you see the [documentation for `TestResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult)?  You have a `TextTestResult` instance, which is a subclass of `TestResult`.  What are you having difficulty getting out of it?  What do you mean "re-load" the code?